# Salesforce image downloading

Tags: ios, ios7, salesforce, salesforce-service-cloud, salesforce-chatter

After login to the salesforce in my app I am making service call which returns the list of products with attributes like productName and product image url.

I am trying to download the image from product image url in this way

```
SFOAuthCredentials *credentials =[SFAccountManager sharedInstance].credentials;

NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@?oauth_token=%@",imageUrl,credentials.accessToken];

NSURL *imgUrl = [[NSURL alloc] initWithString:[URLString stringByAddingPercentEscapesUsingEncoding: NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    NSURLRequest *imgRequest=[[NSURLRequest alloc]initWithURL:imgUrl];
    [NSURLConnection sendAsynchronousRequest:imgRequest queue:[NSOperationQueue mainQueue] completionHandler:^(NSURLResponse *response, NSData *data, NSError *connectionError) {
        UIImage *image=[[UIImage alloc] initWithData:data];
        NSLog(@"Image Object %@",image);
    }];
```

I am getting the data object of size around 1820 bytes, but while converting NSData to UIImage by using UIImage classsMethod [UIImage iamgeWithData:data] or instance method [UIImage alloc] initWithData:data] I am getting null

Can anyone help me to fix this issue?.

Comment: start by checking the http status code you get back.